# Firebase firestore has unsecure rules warning - how do I fix is my app doesn't have authentication

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My firestore has the following rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

My app has no authentication, it is only displaying data.

The only time the firestore is written to is in a simple email sign up form that I want anyone to be able to submit and when an order is checked out from the cart that happens on the back end.

What rules do I need to set for this scenario?

Comment: We can't write your rules for you because we know nothing specific about how your app needs to write to Firestore.  You should first study the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to understand what rules can do, and make an attempt at implementing what you need.  If something doesn't work the way you expect, then please post here with your debugging details.

Comment: Honestly, you use-case sounds pretty scary already: it sounds like anyone can submit their personal data in a sign-up form and then *everyone* in the world can read that. Is that really the intended use-case of your app?

Comment: Instead of calling people names, perhaps you could edit the question to be more clear about what your specific use case specifically requires, what you tried that doesn't work (after studying the documentation), and what isn't working the way you expect.